# How to take z-transform of a function with an absolute exponent value?

Tags: signal, dsp

Can you help me find the z-transform of the impulse response below:

$$h(n) = (\frac{1}{2})^{|n-1|} + (\frac{1}{2})^{|n|} $$

I know the z-transform of 
 $$(\frac{1}{2})^{n}$$
 is equal to:
 $$(\frac{z}{z-b})$$

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the expression by segmenting it to two intervals

- \$ u(n)\$  \$\space\space\space\space\space\$  for \$ n>0 \$
- \$ u(-n-1)\$ \$\space\space\$  for \$n < 0\$

$$h(n) = (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}u(n) + (\frac{1}{2})^{n}u(n) +(\frac{1}{2})^{-n+1}u(-n-1) + (\frac{1}{2})^{-n}u(-n-1) $$

According to the superposition theorem, z-transform of two or more functions is the same as taking the z-transform of each one individually, and then adding them. Same Applies here.

[image]

Lastly, you need to determine region of convergence